# C++ Structures, file does not compile, vector array has issues

Tags: c++, function, vector, data-structures, compiler-errors

I do not understand what is wrong but it seems like the problem lies with the vector, but after searching on the internet I could not solve this issue.

The error from the compiler looks like this:

```
main.cpp:25:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
   25 |     getdata(student &s,file);
      |                     ^
main.cpp:26:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
   26 |     printdata(student &s,file);
      |                       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void getdata(student&, std::fstream)’:
main.cpp:36:15: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘student’ and ‘int’)
   36 |         cin>>s[i].name;
      |               ^
main.cpp:38:15: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘student’ and ‘int’)
   38 |         cin>>s[i].sno;
      |               ^
main.cpp:40:15: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘student’ and ‘int’)
   40 |         cin>>s[i].mark;
      |               ^
main.cpp:44:34: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘student’ and ‘int’)
   44 |         file<<"Student name: "<<s[i].name<<endl;
      |                                  ^
main.cpp:45:36: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘student’ and ‘int’)
   45 |         file<<"Student number: "<<s[i].snum<<endl;
      |                                    ^
main.cpp:46:33: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘student’ and ‘int’)
   46 |         file<<"term mark:   "<<s[i].mark<<endl;
      |                                 ^
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string name;
    int snum;
    double mark;
};

void getdata(student &s,fstream file);
void printdata(student &s,fstream file);

int main ()
{
    fstream file;
    int number;
    vector <student> s(3);

    cout<<"Enter number of students to account for: "<<endl;
    cin>>number;
    
    getdata(student &s,file);
    printdata(student &s,file);

}

void getdata(student &s, fstream file)
{
    file.open("Students.txt",ios::out);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter your name: "<<endl;
        cin>>s[i].name;
        cout<<"Enter your student number: "<<endl;
        cin>>s[i].sno;
        cout<<"Enter your term mark: "<<endl;
        cin>>s[i].mark;
        cout<<endl;
        
        file<<"----------------------"<<endl;
        file<<"Student name: "<<s[i].name<<endl;
        file<<"Student number: "<<s[i].snum<<endl;
        file<<"term mark:   "<<s[i].mark<<endl;
        file<<"----------------------"<<endl;
        
    }
    file.close();
}

void printdata(student &s, fstream file)
{
    file.open("Students.txt",ios::in);
    string read;
    while(getline(cin,read))
    {
        cout<<read<<endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: In `void getdata(student &s, fstream file)`  the variable `s` is a reference to a single student. It's not a vector of students. Also I don't like the use of magic numbers. You have `3` hard coded in several places. What happens if the file does not have 3 students. What happens if later you want 4 students. Also you ask the user to enter the `number` of students but then ignore there answer and operate on 3.

Comment: There is nothing here that relates to the purpose of [tag:file]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not valid function calls:

```
getdata(student &s,file);
printdata(student &s,file);
```

They should be:

```
getdata(s,file);
printdata(s,file);
```

That will cause other errors because your functions clearly expect a `vector<student>`, but only take a `student`.

You also cannot pass `fstream` objects by value.  They must be references.

Change your function parameter lists to look like this:

```
void getdata(vector<student> &s, fstream &file);
void printdata(vector<student> &s, fstream &file);
```

There's also a typo with the member `.sno` which you meant `.snum`

Fix all this and your program will compile, then you can at least start debugging it to see if it even works.